# Can I use HyperX with Snabbdom

Tags: virtual-dom, hyperscript

`HyperX` is a module that translates a tagged template literal to a `hyperscript` function like the one included with `virtual-dom`.

`Snabbdom` uses a hyperscript-like function to build it's vdoms, but it's second argument is different. Instead of attributes it's properties are used by various "modules";

```
h('div', {
  props: {title: someString}, // snabbdom/modules/props
  classes: {selected: isSelected}, // snabbdom/modules/class
  on: {click: doSomething}, // snabbdom/modules/eventlisteners
  style: {color: someColor} // snabbdom/modules/style
}, ['children']);
```

Is it possible to use `hyperx` with `snabbdom`'s hyperscript function like so:

```
const h = require('snabbdom/h');
const hyperx = require('hyperx');
const hx = hyperx(h);

let vdom = hx`
  <div 
    title=${someString} 
    class-selected={isSelected} 
    on-click={doSomething} 
    style={({color: someColor})}
  >
   children
  </div>
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can!

```js
var snabbdom = require('snabbdom')
var patch = snabbdom.init([ // Init patch function with chosen modules
  require('snabbdom/modules/class'), // makes it easy to toggle classes
  require('snabbdom/modules/props'), // for setting properties on DOM elements
  require('snabbdom/modules/style') // handles styling on elements with support for animations  
])
var h = require('snabbdom/h')
var hyperx = require('hyperx')
var hx = hyperx(h)

var title = 'world'
var wow = [1,2,3]
var tree = hx`<div>
  <h1 y="ab${1+2}cd">hello ${title}!</h1>
  ${hx`<i>cool</i>`}
  wow
  ${wow.map(function (w, i) {
    return hx`<b>${w}</b>\n`
  })}
</div>` 
patch(document.body, tree)
```

**check the working code [here](http://requirebin.com/?gist=ebb5c17efe1db112805aebd37fa524d1)**

Comment: The attributes in your example don't work. The <h1> doesn't have a 'y' attribute. Children seem to work, but you can't attach eventlisteners, classes, styles, or other attributes.

Comment: I see. It seems to be that the patch function can't render the vnode object generated with hyperx, at least not all things. I tried including all modules, for eventlistener and attributes specifically, but it makes no difference.
I also inspect the `tree` object and it has the attributes, that's why I conclude that the patch function isn't working right